# Pandas - Split and refactor and overloaded ID column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas` `DataFrame` with columns `patient_id`, `patient_sex`, `patient_dob` (and other less relevant columns). Rows can have duplicate `patient_id`s, as each patient may have more than one entry in the data for multiple medical procedures. I discovered, however, that a great many of the `patient_id`s are overloaded, i.e. more than one patient has been assigned to the same id (evidenced by many instances of a single `patient_id` being associated with multiple sexes and multiple days of birth).

To refactor the ids so that each patient has a unique one, my plan was to group the data not only by `patient_id`, but by `patient_sex` and `patient_dob` as well. I figure this must be sufficient to separate the data into individual users (and if two patients with the same sex and dob just happened to be assigned the same id, then so be it.

Here is the code I currently use:

```
# I just use first() here as a way to aggregate the groups into a DataFrame.
# Bonus points if you have a better solution!
indv_patients = patients.groupby(['patient_id', 'patient_sex', 'patient_dob']).first()

# Create unique ids
new_patient_id = 'new_patient_id'
for index, row in indv_patients.iterrows():
    # index is a tuple of the three column values, so this should get me a unique 
    # patient id for each patient
    indv_patients.loc[index, new_patient_id] = str(hash(index))

# Merge new ids into original patients frame
patients_with_new_ids = patients.merge(indv_patients, left_on=['patient_id', 'patient_sex', 'patient_dob'], right_index=True)

# Remove byproduct columns, and original id column
drop_columns = [col for col in patients_with_new_ids.columns if col not in patients.columns or col == new_patient_id]
drop_columns.append('patient_id')
patients_with_new_ids = patients_with_new_ids.drop(columns=drop_columns)

patients = patients_with_new_ids.rename(columns={new_patient_id : 'patient_id'})
```

The problem is that with over 7 million patients, this is way too slow a solution, the biggest bottleneck being the for-loop. So my question is, is there a better way to fix these overloaded ids? (The actual id doesn't matter, so long as its unique for each patient)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the values for the columns are but have you tried something like this?

```
patients['new_patient_id'] = patients.apply(lambda x: x['patient_id'] + x['patient_sex'] + x['patient_dob'],axis=1)
```

This should create a new column and you can then use groupby with the new_patient_id

Comment: Wow, I waaaaaaay overcomplicated that. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, and there's a small typo, `lamda` should be `lambda` but I can't edit it :
)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo. Great that it worked for your case